# Three positive point charges are located on a line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coulombs-law

I need some help resolving the follow problem. I really don't know where to put the "twice as large as the resultant force on Q3" in order to build an equation. What I found till now is that F2,1 is 0.81.

Q2 = 3 Microcoulombs
Q3 = 6 Microcoulombs
The distance between Q2 and Q3 is 2 meters

Q1(+)-------------Q2(+)-------------Q3(+)

If the charge of Q2 is subjected to a resultant force of 54⋅E-3 N to the right, and the magnitude of
the resultant force on Q1 is twice as large as the resultant force on Q3,
determine the value of Q1 and the distance between Q1 & Q2

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The following approach may be helpful.
The force on charge $x$ due to charge $y$ is written as $F_{xy}$ in what appears below.  Furthermore, note that $F_{xy}=-F_{yx}$ and positive values for the forces are towards the right.

$$
F_{21}+F_{23}=54E{-3} \left( \text{N} \right) \quad \left(1\right)
$$

I believe the "twice as large..." constraint is addressed by equation (2) below:
$$
F_{12}+F_{13}=-2\left(F_{31}+F_{32}\right) \quad \left(2\right)
$$

From Coulomb's Law:
$$
F_{32}=\frac{8.99E9 \times 3E{-6} \times 6E{-6}}{2^{2}}=40.4E{-3} \left( \text{N} \right) \quad \left(3\right)
$$

Using Eq. (1), we can calculate

$$
F_{21}=94.4E{-3} \left( \text{N} \right)
$$

Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction to determine all the remaining unknowns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I manage to find the F21 by using the Ti-Nspire and solve, but the issue that I have is to find Q1 and d

I tried to do a solve ( on my Ti-Nspire), I can't manage to find, probably i'm using the wrong equation:

F21 + -F23 = 54E-3 
-F12+-F13 = 2 * (F31 + F32)

The calculator can't calculate it, I did also that d is lower than 100, but no answers.

Thanks again !